# 'Is not assignable' Type error using generic for sorting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-tsx

Duplicated here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sea-uu3l8?file=/src/BoxBox.tsx

I've stripped this down and I think the error is close to what I'm getting with the full blown code. I'm using the mui sort [example](https://mui.com/components/tables/#EnhancedTable.tsx) but I'm getting an error when the generic getComparator is called **rows.slice().sort(getComparator(order, orderBy))**.

Error: Argument of type '(a: { [x: string]: string | number | Date; }, b: { [x: string]: string | number | Date; }) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Bob, b: Bob) => number'.
Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
Type 'Bob' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: string | number | Date; }'.
Index signature is missing in type 'Bob'.ts(2345)

```
function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

type Order = 'asc' | 'desc';

function getComparator<Key extends keyof any>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: Key,
): (
    a: { [key in Key]: number | string | Date },
    b: { [key in Key]: number | string | Date },
  ) => number {
  return order === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}
```

Comment: the link seems to be empty

Comment: Fixed it I think. Try it again?

Comment: your code sandbox is still empty, but given the error message i think that you are passing the entire object "Bob" to the comparator, whereas you should only be passing one of the properties of the object, like `Bob.name` to the comparator, that's what's the error is trying to say atleast.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Ok, thanks. You should be able to see the code sandbox now. Also, I'm confused by your answer as this is how MUI's example usage: rows.slice().sort(getComparator(order, orderBy))

https://codesandbox.io/s/sumje?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course it is not going to let you the problem is hard to see in your code
...with all respect please take it as a constructive criticism...

the Error is because `getComparator` gets two parameters of type `{ [key in Key]: number | string | Date }` but on the other hand `descendingComparator` receives two parameters of type `T` in other words `T !== { [key in Key]: number | string | Date }`

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

type Order = "asc" | "desc";

function getComparator<Key extends keyof Bob>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: Key
): (a: Bob, b: Bob) => number {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

interface Bob {
  aDate: Date;
  bDate: Date;
  status: string;
  cDate: Date;
  cost: number;
  costId: number;
  personId: number | null;
  itemAmount: number | null;
  notes: string;
}

function createData(
  aDate: Date,
  bDate: Date,
  status: string,
  cDate: Date,
  cost: number,
  costId: number,
  personId: number | null,
  itemAmount: number | null,
  notes: string
): Bob {
  return {
    aDate,
    bDate,
    status,
    cDate,
    cost,
    costId,
    personId,
    itemAmount,
    notes
  };
}

const stuff = [
  createData(
    new Date("2018-05-01"),
    new Date("2018-05-31"),
    "rfds",
    new Date("2018-05-01"),
    20.4,
    24703,
    null,
    0,
    "fdls;akj"
  ),
  createData(
    new Date("2018-05-01"),
    new Date("2018-05-31"),
    "gfaer",
    new Date("2018-05-01"),
    20.4,
    24703,
    null,
    0,
    "fdls;akj"
  )
];

const BobBox: FC = () => {
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState<keyof Bob>("Status");
  const [order, setOrder] = useState<Order>("asc");

  return (
    <Box component={Paper}>
      {stuff
        .slice()
        .sort(getComparator(order, orderBy))
        .map((item, i) => (
          <Box key={i}>{item.status}</Box>
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <BobBox />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm really trying to understand why MUI's example works then. What's the difference?! Thoughts?
https://mui.com/components/tables/#EnhancedTable.tsx

Comment: is the same problem,
yow Bob obj is not the same as `Bob !== the other thing` I updated my post, please hit the like button an subscribe